# 9 Digits Unique ID through the day

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

Having one puzzling requirement.

Basically I need to create unique id with these criteria

- 9 digits number, unique for the day (means it's ok if the number appears again the next day )
- generated in realtime ; java only ( means no sequence number generation from database -actually no database access at all )
- the number is generated to populate a requestID, and around 1.000.000 id will be generated per day.
- UUID or UID should not be used ( more than 9 digits )

Here is my consideration :

- using sequence number sounds good, but in case JVM restart, the
  requestId might be re-generated.
- using time HHmmssSSS ( Hour Minute Second Milliseconds ) have 2 issues :

> a. System Hour might be changed by server admin.
>   b. Can cause issue
>   if 2 requests being asked on same milliseconds.

Any idea?

Comment: Basing this on wall time still seems like the best option. Even if admins adjust time, this takes place gradually and would not disrupt your function.

Comment: Why only 9 digits?  How many servers will be handling requests?

Comment: @RayToal forgot to mention. 2 servers on Load Balancing (!!!) I don't really know why it's 9 digits though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nine digits to handle 1,000,000 IDs gives us three digits to play with (we need the other six for the 0-999999 for the ID).

I assume you have a multi-server setup. Assign each server a three-digit server ID, and then you can allocate unique ID values within each server without worrying about overlap between them. It can just be an ever-increasing value in memory, except to survive JVM restarts, we need to echo the most recently allocated value to disk (well, to anywhere you want to store it — local disk, memcache, whatever).

To ensure you don't hit the overhead of file/whatever I/O on each request, you allocate the IDs in blocks, echoing the endpoint of the block back to the storage.

So it ends up being:

- Give each server an ID
- Have storage on the server which stores the last allocated value for the day (a file, for instance)
- Have the ID allocator work in blocks (10 IDs at a time, 100, whatever)
- To allocate a block:

  - Read the file, write back a number increased by your blocksize
- Use IDs from the block
- The ID would be , e.g. 12000000027 for the 28th ID allocated by server #12
- When the day changes (e.g., midnight), throw away your current block and allocate a new one for the new day

In **pseudocode**:

```
class IDAllocator {
    Storage storage;
    int     nextId;
    int     idCount;
    int     blockSize;
    long    lastIdTime;

    /**
     * Creates an IDAllocator with the given server ID, backing storage,
     * and block size.
     *
     * @param   serverId        the ID of the server (e.g., 12)
     * @param   s               the backing storage to use
     * @param   size            the block size to use
     * @throws  SomeException   if something goes wrong
     */
    IDAllocator(int serverId, Storage s, int size)
    throws SomeException {

        // Remember our info
        this.serverId = serverId * 1000000; // Add a million to make life easy
        this.storage = s;
        this.nextId = 0;
        this.idCount = 0;
        this.blockSize = bs;
        this.lastIdTime = this.getDayMilliseconds();

        // Get the first block. If you like and depending on
        // what container this code is running in, you could
        // spin this out to a separate thread.
        this.getBlock();
    }

    public synchronized int getNextId()
    throws SomeException {
        int id;

        // If we're out of IDs, or if the day has changed, get a new block
        if (idCount == 0 || this.lastIdTime < this.getDayMilliseconds()) {
            this.getBlock();
        }

        // Alloc from the block    
        id = this.nextId;
        --this.idCount;
        ++this.nextId;

        // If you wanted (and depending on what container this
        // code is running in), you could proactively retrieve
        // the next block here if you were getting low...

        // Return the ID
        return id + this.serverId;
    }

    protected long getDayMilliseconds() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 86400000;
    }

    protected void getBlock()
    throws SomeException {
        int id;

        synchronized (this) {
            synchronized (this.storage.syncRoot()) {
                id = this.storage.readIntFromStorage();
                this.storage.writeIntToStroage(id + blocksize);
            }

            this.nextId = id;
            this.idCount = blocksize;
        }
    }
}
```

...but again, that's pseudocode, and you might want to throw some proactive stuff in there so you never block on I/O waiting for an ID when you need one.

The above is written assuming you already have some kind of application-wide singleton, and the `IDAllocator` instance would just be a data member in that single instance. If not, you could readily make the above a singleton instead, by giving it the classic `getInstance` method and having it read its configuration from the environment rather than receiving it as arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something?  1,000,000 IDs per day only requires 6 digits (assuming that 000000 is a valid ID). So some digits are available for 'partitioning' the ID space among servers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I **really** need to get my first cup of coffee in me before doing anything on SO. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be a Singleton in order to avoid two clients creating an instance of this class and generating the same ids? Or you can synchronize the `getNextId` method on `IDAllocator.class`

Comment: @mavroprovato: Hey, it's pseudocode. :-) But I wrote it thinking you'd create an instance of the class on startup, not per client. Making this a singleton is certainly an option, but not a requirement *if* the OP has another application-level object already (as many do) which is the container for things like this. If it were a singleton, we'd want it to read its config from somewhere rather than receiving it as arguments, of course.

Answer (score 5):

> no sequence number generation from database

I hate silly requirements like that. I say you cheat and use an embedded database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) and generate the identifier through a sequence.

**Edit:** Let me expand I bit on why I propose this "cheat": My understanding on the "No database" requirement is that either no database software should be installed to handle this requirement or that the existing database schema cannot be changed. Using an embedded database is the same thing as adding a new jar file to your project. Why you should not do this? Why implement something yourself when relational databases have already solved this problem for you?

Comment: Has to survive JVM shutdown/startup, apparently.

Comment: Embedded databases do not have to be in memory, they can be saved in persistent storage too.

Comment: Right. Which he said he didn't want to do. (The requirements are pretty arbitrary.) How do you solve multiple-server ID conflicts?

Comment: Sorry, I re-read the question twice, I cannot see where he said that he should not use persistent storage. Neither can I see what this multi-server requirement is. I thought that only one server will generate the ids for multiple clients.

Comment: The question is quite vague and really should be closed as it appears to have been abandoned (no answers to useful follow-up questions), but he said "no sequence number generation from database," which to me pretty much means "no sequence number generation from database."

Comment: No H2 or HSQLDB also since it has to pass client security review. But yes, I agree that this is some kind of silly requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What about counting from 1 to 999.999.999 for server 1.
And counting from -999.999.999 to -1 for server 2.

I guess due to load balancing the balancing would be about 50:50. So you got the same id range for each server. In addition you store the last generated id on your filesystem. Due to performance issues just store every 1000. value (or 10000, it doesn't really matter). After restarting your application read the last generated value and add 1000. I guess that would work.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Simply divide the number range from 1 to 999.999.999 in 2 groups and you are done. group 1: 1 - 499.999.999, group 2: 500.000.000 - 999.999.999. Simply format the numbers so 1 would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try out Apache's [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) [String random(int count,                            boolean letters, boolean numbers)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#random%28int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) or try and use the [Java TRNG Client library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trng-random-org/) which in turn makes use of RANDOM.ORG:

> This library provides a SecureRandom service, integrated with the Java
>   Security API, for accessing random.org and random.irb.hr (true random
>   number generators that generates randomness via atmospheric noise or
>   photonic emission).

I think that if you get one of those and combine it with a time stamp, you should get what you are after.

Comment: timestamp part + random, as long as he isn't using the timestamp as the random seed it should be okay. of course can't prove mathematically that it will not clash, but if the requirements are to make these in multiple threads which are not aware of each other then there's no way to guarantee that the id's don't clash. one solution could be to run a service just for generating the id's, which all threads from all servers would ask for the id, that service could of course be a db or something dumber than a full blown db. once that's sorted out it becomes trivial to ensure that the id's are uniq.

Comment: @npinti: I **really** need to get my first cup of coffee in me before doing anything on SO. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No worries. I thought I was missing something which was staring straight in my face.